# Using Prince library for MCA and FAMD in python

Tags: python-3.x, pca, factor-analysis, correspondence-analysis

How to perform Factor Analysis of Mixed Data (FAMD) on the **train and test datasets**?

Generally, to apply sklearn PCA the following code is used:

```
pca=PCA(n_components=30).fit(X_train)
PC_train=pca.transform(X_train)
PC_test=pca.transform(X_test)
```

However, when I use the [**prince package**](https://github.com/MaxHalford/prince#factor-analysis-of-mixed-data-famd) the `.transform()` cannot be applied to the test set. It gives value error as shown below?

```
from prince import FAMD
famd = FAMD().fit(X_train)
PC_train=famd.transform(X_train)
PC_test=famd.transform(X_test)
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your error message as text, not an image.

Answer (score 1):

FAMD has to be fitted (using `.fit()`) on the data and then the `famd.transform()` can be applied on that same data. You should use:

```
famd = FAMD().fit(X_test)
PC_test=famd.transform(X_test)
```